# .html() can't load background-color from div?

Tags: jquery, html

i'm using this script to load content of a div, inside another div, but the background color propertie of this div isn't load.

Here my code:

My menu:

```
<nav class="navegacao">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#empresa">Empresa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery_wrapper">Coleções</a></li>
        <li><a href="#encotre">Encontre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#diferenciais">Diferenciais</a></li>
        <li><a href="#marketing">Marketing</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here my content div recipiente:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<!--content-->
<section id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="splash"></div>
    </div>
</section>
 <!--content end-->
</div>
```

Here my hidden div:

```
<div id="home">TESTE</div>
```

Here my CSS:

```
#content_wrapper > #content {
    padding: 48px 78px 30px 78px;
    margin: 135px 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 372px;
    width: 791px;
    /*background:#fff;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#home{
    width:500;
    height:500px;
    background:#FFCC00;
    display:none;
}
```

And here my Swap content code:

```
$(function() {
        $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var h = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#content").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).html($(h).html()).fadeIn("slow");
            });
            //alert(h);
        });
    });
```

How to make this working?

OBS: Here is the working link with the problem: http://www.alsite.com.br/sapatoterapia/

Comment: why are you calling `$(h).html()` and not `h.html()`

Comment: Because `h` is just the String of the `href`

Comment: feel free to indicate my 'rightness' with an upvote :)

Comment: hehe i always forget that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

OK so I just realized your issues you are trying to load #home's style into #content - well this won't work... #home's styles are only for the element with the ID home... now you have the content from home in the #content container..

you can try this

```
var h = $("#home").detach(); // remove the element from the dom... maybe?? but you will now have to re-attach it when you're switching to a new page.
$(this).html("").append(h).fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: you shouldn't have to detach it if you are appending it

Comment: I didn't know jQuery took care of that. I would have assumed it cloned the node. Either way I would think he would need to take care of re-inserting it into the DOM when he's done with it.

Comment: i could not use `var h = $("#home").detach();` because the `h` receives the `href` valor of the menu i have clicked. Instead i can use `var h = $(this).attr('href').detach();`??

Comment: close... `$(this.href).detach()` iirc there was a little thing called the DOM before the days of jQuery... it's amazing it still exists :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$(h).html()` you're getting the HTML ***within*** the `<div>` but not the `<div>` itself. If you want the full hidden dive in there, try:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var h = $($(this).attr('href'));
        h.remove().css('display','block');
        $("#content").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).html($(h)).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Edited: Changed `h` so it would actually be the jQuery object, then removed it form the DOM and set it's display to `block` (since it's set to `none` in the css). That way when you append it back in, it is the only ID on the page (keeping it unique) and it should be visible.

Edited again to try and make it work for what you're doing:
Why not put your hidden divs inside the content div.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="splash"></div>
    <div id="home"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Since they're `display:none` you'll still get the look you want. Then, in your code, just hide/show instead of actually moving stuff around:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var h = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#content").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).find('div').hide().siblings(h).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

When a user clicks a link, it will fade out the content, hide all the divs inside, then fade in the one associated with the click.

Comment: Edited to make sure we have only unique IDs on the page and to make sure it's visible.

Comment: Though I don't think you're actually going to want to do this, because it will only work the first time you click the link since it is removed from the DOM. You really need some restructuring of your code

Comment: yeah .. only work one time, if the user click in another menu item and back to the first, this not work. Btw.. thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Does changing this line

```
$(this).html($(h).html()).fadeIn("slow");
```

to

```
$(this).html($(h).wrap('<div />').parent().html()).fadeIn("slow");
```

and add this css

```
#content > div{
   display:block !important;
}
```

help ?

Comment: Yes, because you have `display:none` by default for hidden elements. 
Updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS problem not a jQuery problem. You need to use CSS to style the div in its new home **OR** use inline styling that will travel with the div `style="background:someColor"`.

Part of the issue is that you are only getting the **CONTENTS** of #home, not making a new div with the same properties. Give `$(h).clone()` a shot instead of `$(h).html()`